# Why does Streamlit crash when accessing Plotly full_figure_for_development

Tags: plotly, streamlit

I need to access the current x and y range of a Plotly chart.  Plotly provides a [function](https://plotly.com/python/figure-introspection/#accessing-javascriptcomputed-defaults)  to access these values. However when I try to display the Plot in Streamlit the application crashes with no output shown in in the Python console.

I have used the following code. When rerunning the app there is no output and the App freezes

```
import streamlit as st
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import kaleido

fig = go.Figure(
    data=[go.Scatter(
        mode="markers+text",
        x=[10,20],
        y=[20, 10],
        text=["Point A", "Point B"]
    )],
    layout=dict(height=400, width=400, template="none")
)
st.plotly_chart(fig)
full_fig = fig.full_figure_for_development()
print(full_fig)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine with the following versions:

python 3.10.12
streamlit 1.23.1
plotly 5.15.0
kaleido 0.2.1

If you still have the problem, maybe check the memory consumption.

Comment: I checked memory consumption and with 50 to 100mb it doesnt seem unusually high. I am working on kaleido==0.2.1 plotly==5.16.1 streamlit==1.25.0 but also encountered the problem on older versions